# Inserting Javascript variable into PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to paste two variables from javascript to PHP so I tried

```
$.post("index.php", {myQuery: myFinalSQL, action: "show_all_stories_sorting"});
```

where myFinalSQL is a string in javascript

In index.php, I try to printout the myFinalSQL with

```
echo $_POST['myQuery'];
```

But it didn't work. Would you please tell me how to insert javascript variables to PHP?

Comment: Define "it didn't work".  Where there any errors on the JavaScript console?  Any errors in the PHP logs?  Was the AJAX request made at all?  Did it include the value(s) you expected?  What was the server's response?  What did you do with that response?  (Hint: The code shown ignores the response.)  What is the *actual* code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You using wrong approach.

It is bad way to interract with server by such method (inserting php variable in `<? ?>` tags into script tag).

You should use this:

```
$.post("ajax.php/myGlobalAction", params, callback);
```

In callback you will do with your data all what you need.

Example:

```
var params = {
 id: 5
};
$.post( "ajax.php?action=getSqlQueryForSomething", params , function( data ) {
   $( ".sqlQuery" ).html( data.sqlQuery );
});
```

So you have complex architecture problem if you need to work with php and js like this. Change your architecture before it's too late.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your suggestion but the page didnt refresh with the new content. Do I have to use header() method? The index.php file include the Homepage_top.php and Homepage_bottom.php and a list of actions. The Homepage_top include the Jquery click function which I used to call $.post to paste the SQL string to the Homepage_bottom.php. which includes the content that I extract from database.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add value from PHP to Javascript you can use :

```
<script>
    var myQuery = "<?php echo $myQuery; ?>;
</script>
```

But, if you want to add value from Javascript to PHP, you'r not allowed because PHP is server based and javascript is text based.

If you used `$.post()` :

```
$.post("index.php", {myQuery: myFinalSQL}, *your_javascript_action* );
```

in your index.php, you can use this :

```
if(isset($_POST['myQuery'])){ // checking method
    echo $_POST['myQuery'];
}
```